# How to unwrap a Map when returning xml from controller

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson

I'm working on SpringBoot 1.5.16 project.
I got a result, returned by my service as a LinkedHashMap. My controller returns this map in xml format. I get something like this:

```
   <LinkedHashMap>
     <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
       <GrpHdr>
         ....
     </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
  </LinkedHashMap>
```

I would like to get rid of `<LinkedHashMap></LinkedHashMap>`.
I tried to create a wrapper class with jackson annotation, but it didn't help:

```
   @Data
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class XmlWrapper {
      @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
      private final Map data;
   }
```

And result was like this:

```
    <XmlWrapper>
      <data>
        <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
          <GrpHdr>
            ...
       </data>
    </XmlWrapper>
```

I also tried to add something like this:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map getData() {
    return data;
}
```

It brings me back to the initial case. Is there any good way to solve this problem without creating XmlMapper and editing the serialized string by hands?

Comment: You want to give LinkedHashMap whatever name, that's all?

Comment: I want to unwrap it totally. Remove <LinkedHashMap></LinkedHashMap>. So it starts like <CstmrCdtTrfInitn><GrpHdr>

Comment: What are the types of Map's key and value?

Comment: It's a nested Map: key is always String and value can be either LinkedHashMap or String. (That's how multilevel xml file is parsed in a Map by Jackson)